# SMS message to AIM screen name

Tags: android, sms, aim

Is it possible to send a SMS text message to a AIM screen name? I am trying to do this in my Android application.

Comment: You probably want to send a AIM message to a AIM screen name, there must be an API for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no Android API that will take a phone number, an SMS message, and somehow convert that SMS into an AIM that magically goes to the right person- They're different technologies, with different addressing schemes (number vs aol screen name).  It's sort of like asking if you can call a website :)

However, there is at least one [service](http://lifehacker.com/279816/use-aim-over-sms) that lets you use SMS as an in-between step to send AIM messeges-  You send them to the SMS address, and the server listening to that address picks up the AIM name and forwards it to the correct location from there.